# Wordpress create subfolder in uploads directory from plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, mkdir

I am writing a plugin that requires that I create a subfolder within the uploads directory.

Here's what I have tried thus far:

```
$uploads_dir = trailingslashit( wp_upload_dir( dirname( __FILE__) ) ) . '/evaluation-uploads';
wp_mkdir_p( $uploads_dir );
```

However when I check 'wp-content/uploads/' the subfolder has not been created.

Comment: check `$uploads_dir`, rights of user that runs php, and rights for `wp-content/uploads/` dir

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use this modified version:

```
$uploads_dir = trailingslashit( wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] ) . 'evaluation-uploads';
wp_mkdir_p( $uploads_dir );
```

(Will only work on PHP 5.4+)

Corrections made:

- No need to pass `dirname( __FILE__)` as parameter to [`wp_upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/)
- Also [`wp_upload_dir`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) returns an array, so you need to access the path you need
- [`trailingslashit`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/trailingslashit/) will already remove **and** append a new trailing slash, so removed it from your string

Also check file/dir user-permissions to ensure PHP can actually create a dir there.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Missing a parenthesis after ['basedir'] :)

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
 $upload = wp_upload_dir();
 $upload_dir = $upload['basedir'];
 $upload_dir = $upload_dir . '/mypluginfiles';
 if (! is_dir($upload_dir)) {
    mkdir( $upload_dir, 0700 );
 }
```

Comment: By using "wp_mkdir_p" instead of using "mkdir" we can omit the "if" condition and setting file permissions since "wp_mkdir_p" will automatically handle those for you.